# OSX bash script - awk i/o error occured on /dev/stdin - converting fixed-width to tab-delimited and converting space-delimited to tab-delimited

Tags: macos, bash, file-io, awk

I have a bash script for running both in Linux and OSX. This script works fine in Linux, but when I try it on OSX, it fails: `awk: i/o error occurred on /dev/stdin`. I am using `awk` to input either a fixed-width or a space-delimited file and output a (temporary) tab-delimited file for playing with, and then I delete the file when I'm done.

```
#!/bin/bash

.... # lots of commands

# for space-delimited to tab-delimited
awk < input_spaces.txt 'BEGIN{ FS=" "; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' > temp_file.txt

.... # some stuff using temp_file.txt

rm temp_file.txt

# for fixed-width to tab-delimited    
awk < input_tabs.txt 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "32 3 10 9 8 8 9"; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}' > temp_file.txt

.... # some stuff using temp_file.txt

rm temp_file.txt

.... # lots of other commands
```

Error message:

```
awk: i/o error occurred on /dev/stdin
```

for all occurrences of the discussed use of `awk`.

Alternatively:

```
#!/bin/bash

.... # lots of commands

# for space-delimited to tab-delimited
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" "; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' input_spaces.txt > temp_file.txt

cat temp_file.txt

.... # some stuff using temp_file.txt

rm temp_file.txt

# for fixed-width to tab-delimited    
awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "32 3 10 9 8 8 9"; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}' input_tabs.txt > temp_file.txt

cat temp_file.txt

.... # some stuff using temp_file.txt

rm temp_file.txt

.... # lots of other commands
```

... results in empty temp_file.txt (on OSX `cat temp_file.txt` returns nothing, while on Linux it still works fine).

None of the research I have done on the error leads anywhere useful/helpful, but it seems to be a common problem on OSX. I have tried many other formulations for using `awk` within my bash script (as posted in numerous places online), but so far, none have worked on both systems. Also, I do not have access to `gawk` because I do not have administrative (`sudo`) privileges on the Mac.

So, any other ideas on how I could convert these files within a bash script and have it work on both systems? I want to avoid altering the original files. Thanks!

(Sorry if I am missing something obvious. I haven't used `awk` before.)

input_tabs.txt (the fixed-width input file) looks like this:

```
Zyxw:
abcdef(ghijklm = no.pqrs(tuvwx.yzab$cdefghi) ~ jklmn.opqr$stu[[vwxy$zabcdefg]],      hijklmnopqrs = tuvw$xyz_abcdefghijkl) 

Abcde fghij klmnopqrstuv (wxyza bc defg)

                                Ab CdefGhIjk  LmnoPqr S.Tuvwx      Y1 Za(>B)   
cdefg.hijk$lmn[[opqr$stuvwxyz]]  2   3.45678 9.012345  6.7890 0.12345  6.789 **
Abcdefghi                       12   3.45678 9.012345         6.78901          
Jklmn                           23   4.56789                  0.12345          
---
Opqrst.uvwxyz:  6 ‘***’ 7.890 ‘**’ 1.23 ‘*’ 4.56 ‘.’ 7.8 ‘ ’ 9
```

input_spaces.txt (the space-delimited input file) looks like this:

```
Firsth eade S Econdhead T-hirdh Fourth he aderishereee
UVWXYZ 0.1234 5.678 901
```

Comment: Have the individual fields got spaces within them?

Comment: The general format of an awk command is `awk 'script' file` not `awk < file`

Comment: Yes, as @MarkSetchell indicated don't try to use `stdin` to read the file simply hand `awk` the filename as an argument and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell & @EtanReisner. With that correction it still does not work on OSX: it results in an empty temp_file.txt. (Like before, it does still work in Linux, just not OSX.) I used the following: `awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" "; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' input_spaces.txt  > temp_file.txt` and `awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "32 3 10 9 8 8 9"; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}' input_tabs.txt > temp_file.txt`

Comment: Have the individual fields got spaces within them?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unfortunately, yes, on some rows there are spaces within the individual fields (which is why I don't want to modify the original file), but not on the line that I am primarily interested in.

Comment: Can you show us the input file - at least in part?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes. I've added it to the question above.

Comment: What happens when you run the offending `awk` command on the command line? What happens if you create a simplified script that ONLY contains the `awk` command? Do the commands in your script that you're not showing perform persistent redirections with `exec`, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but the `Comment` method doesn't allow sensible formatting.

Both files seem to be processed fine on my Mac OSX Mavericks with standard `awk` as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" "; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' space| cat -vet

Firsth^Ieade^IS^IEcondhead^IT-hirdh^IFourth^Ihe^Iaderishereee$
UVWXYZ^I0.1234^I5.678^I901^I^I^I^I$
```

and the fixed width file

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "32 3 10 9 8 8 9"; OFS="\t";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14}' tab | cat -vet
Zyxw:^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
abcdef(ghijklm = no.pqrs(tuvwx.y^Izab^I$cdefghi) ^I~ jklmn.o^Ipqr$stu[^I[vwxy$za^Ibcdefg]],^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
Abcde fghij klmnopqrstuv (wxyza ^Ibc ^Idefg)^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
                                ^IAb ^ICdefGhIjk ^I LmnoPqr ^IS.Tuvwx ^I     Y1 ^IZa(>B)   ^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
cdefg.hijk$lmn[[opqr$stuvwxyz]] ^I 2 ^I  3.45678 ^I9.012345 ^I 6.7890 ^I0.12345 ^I 6.789 **^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
Abcdefghi                       ^I12 ^I  3.45678 ^I9.012345 ^I        ^I6.78901 ^I         ^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
Jklmn                           ^I23 ^I  4.56789 ^I         ^I        ^I0.12345 ^I         ^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
---^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I^I$
```